# /odom to /base_footprint

Tags: navigation, odometry, odom-combined, base-footprint, create

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My question:
Hey everyone, What is the best way to connect odom to base_link? Should I modify the navigation stack to look for odom_combined instead? Or would that be too difficult?

Explanation/background:
I'm using the iRobot create and the package create_node. The package works great and I can send cmd_vel topics via the keyboard and it responds, however in rxgraph i can see the create_node is publishing /odom but it is not being sent to tf and therefore it is not the parent of base_link. When I view the tf tree odom_combined is the parent of base_link and odom is not connected, but none of the navigation stacks care about odom_combined, they only want odom. Running on a modified turtlebot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35637//odom-to-/base_footprint/) by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 600 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2012-06-04**:\

It sounds like you're getting the /odom topic (what rxgraph shows) and the /odom frame confused. Note that all transform messages show up as /tf in rxgraph.  I'm not familiar with the particular packages you're using - if it's all working, why do you need to have a frame named "/odom"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure where to find the `create_node` you are talking about but I guess you are just using a really old version of the turtlebot_node.

On the PR2 and I think also on older turtlebot configurations, `robot_pose_ekf`, a node that implements an extended Kalman filter for fusing IMU and odometry, subscribes to the /odom topic and publishes the transform from odom_combined to base_link (or base_footprint in case of the PR2). All navigation nodes that need to know about the odometry TF frame provide a parameter to change the default frame from odom to odom_combined which is done in all PR2 navigation launch files. In newer Turtlebot launch files, the TF frame name for odometry is odom (parameter `output_frame` [here](http://ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf)) which allows to use the default values for the odometry frame in the navigation nodes.

If you don't have an IMU, I can just guess that the transform odom_combined -> base_link is published by the create_node but to be sure, double check by running `rosrun tf tf_monitor`. In that case, I suggest that you update your robot driver to the current Turtlebot driver (stack [turtlebot](http://ros.org/turtlebot). The Turtlebot is based on the iRobot Create, so the driver will work for you. It provides a few parameters to control how transforms are published. E.g. the following launch file might work:

```
<launch>
  <node name="turtlebot_node" type="turtlebot_node.py" pkg="turtlebot_node">
    <rosparam>
      publish_tf: true
      odom_frame: odom
    </rosparam>
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7